# How to color the background of a row in ant's Table component using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, antd

Hello i want to color the background of a row in ant's Table component. So far i have done this: In my component that i have the table is like this:

```
   <Table
       size='small'
       dataSource={this.state.codesInfo}
       rowClassName={(record, index) => ((record.package_name===null ? styles.backgroundColor : ''))}
       columns={{....}}
```

In my `style.js` i have this

```
 const styles = {
     backgroundColor: #f5b12c,
 }

 export default styles;
```

I import my file that i have my `Table` component like this: `import styles from './style.js'` 
When i `console.log` my `styles.backgroundColor` i can see the color in the log, but the rows are not change colors

Comment: Did you inspect the elements to verify that it has this style, one more thing that hex color should be "#f5b12c"

Comment: @iamphduc, i have the hex color inside `"`, but not working, in my console i see the color that i have imported on css file or you mean something else by saying "inspect the elements to verify that it has this style"

Comment: I mean there is a "Elements" tab in Chrome Devtools where you can inspect the style of the element. If the color exists with strikethrough, try using "#f5b12c important!"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem:

i make a css file

```
.even {
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
 }
```

Imported like this in my file that i have the antd `Table`: `import './style.css'`

and i use it like this:

```
 <Table
    size='small'
    dataSource={this.state.codesInfo}
    rowClassName={(record, index) => ((record.package_name===null ? 'even' : ''))}
    columns={{....}}
```